# Products missing from backend after import

Tags: magento, database, phpmyadmin

My client imported about 70 products into magneto and the all imported properly it seemed, but now only about half of them appear in the catalog ( backend ) searching for the SKU returns no results. I have searched the net for an hour looking for some information on this but I cant find any, furthermore I cant seem to find out how to verify whether the products are in the database or not, I thought I could just look for the products table in phpmyadmin, but Magento's EAV database structure looks more complicated than I'm used to. Does anyone know how to fix this, or even to locate products in the database.

Edit : From talking to the client she thinks that this might have happened after she did a reindex.

Comment: Looking at this another way: I know it sounds like nitpicking, but why does it only *seem* they imported properly? Did you or the client actually check after the import? If you can't confirm they were there in the first place, you're trying to determine why things "disappeared" that might've actually failed during the import (ie. were *never* there). If the information is actually that incomplete, I'd just re-import things and be careful to pay closer attention the next time, so you can identify when the problem really happened. Right now it feels to me there's too much room for speculation.

Comment: I see what you meant, but it was actually only a figure of speech, though probably not a very wise one. The products did actually import properly. At the moment we are trying to re-import the products but are experiencing some difficulty, and a bit of confusion too. ( the skus are critical and we haven't gotten to to bottom of why this re-import is not straightforward)

Comment: Ah, no problem. Just had to ask, to get the "Is it plugged in?" question out of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case actually turned out to be something to do with Microsoft excel. ( There are numerous mentions of problems with using it for CSV import into Magento. The CSV files had french words with accents and graves on the letters and even with the file saved in UTF-8 it still was causing confusion that we couldn't figure out. When we switched to Open Office and saved in UTF-8 it worked perfectly, but that's as much as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what's wrong with this limited amount of information. Let's just start ruling things out. Make sure to check: whether the products are enabled, check their visibility (Catalog, search), if they've been added to a website and whether they have stock and images. Those are the things that usually go wrong with automated uploads. If it's not one of them we can look a bit further.

Comment: Thanks but it's the backend they're missing from, I cant check any of those things, they disappeared from the backend.

Comment: Sorry, misread that one. I'd have to agree with SU though. Reimport them again and pay attention to any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link.That may be helpful.
[Magento product images missing after import products](http://faq.pctrickers.com/magento-images-uploading-errors/)